# Specifying types of variables in pure mathematics and applied mathematics

Tags: soft-question, notation

In pure mathematics, we can write such as "an integer $a$ ..." to specify that $a$ is a given integer or $a$ runs through the ring of integers. But in contexts where mathematics is applied difficulties arise. For example, can we write "a mass $m$..."? It seems weird, for writing so represents not what we mean. Can we write "a price $p$ ..."? It again seems weird. But if we try to avoid this weirdness then we are forced to write "a value $m$ of the mass of an object ..." that is cumbersome!

So I am seeking after suggestions on specifying types of variables in applied mathematics, where "applied mathematics" refers to disciplines as illustrated above.

Comment: Prices and masses are positive reals or rationals.

Comment: Yeah. My point is that $p$ actually represents a real number $> 0$ rather than a price, right? There is no object called a price but there is an object called an integer.

Comment: You rarely talk about 'a mass' or 'a price' but rather '*the* mass *of* [an object]' or '*the* price *of* [an object]'

Comment: Yes, I know this, please see my revision. And this is the cause of the question.

Comment: I don't really see the distinction between the price and the real number representing the price, as long as units are specified to make the real number well-defined, e.g., "Let $p$ represent the price of object $O$, measured in dollars."

Comment: Echoing @PhillipAndreae's comment, _units_ matter in these situations. "Let the price of X be $p$ dollars."

Comment: Well, let us consider mathematical economics. In Debreu's axiomatic treatment (Theory of value) units are fixed out.